# Scrapy crawling data using product API

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, scrapy

I scrape the [**target site**](https://www.mediamarkt.com.tr/tr/category/_android-telefonlar-675172.html) with scrapy. However, there are cache problems on the site and most of the time I can get updated data with a delay of 4-5 minutes. I know some people scrape this site using API. However, I searched the site and couldn't find the API link. I looked for all XHR-type content in the Network section, but could not find it.
How can I scrape the relevant site with API.

My code I am currently using:

```
def parse(self, response):
        for li in response.css('li'):
            item=MediamarktItem()
            script_text = li.css('script::text').extract_first()
            if script_text:
                data = json.loads(re.search(r'var product\d+ = (.*);', script_text).group(1))
                name = data['name']
                price = data['price']
                product_id = data['id']
                

                item['rowid'] = hash(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + product_id)
                item['date'] = str(datetime.datetime.now())
                item['listing_id'] = product_id
                item['product_name'] = name
                item['price'] = price
                item['product_id'] = product_id
                item['url'] = "https://www.mediamarkt.com.tr/tr/product/" + "-" + product_id + '.html'
                item['merchantName'] = "Mediamarkt"
                yield item
```

When I examined the site a little, I saw that it made a request like the one below. But I couldn't figure out how to pull data from url. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
  https://www.mediamarkt.com.tr/tr/product/productlistajax.json
```